# How to get value from PROMISE in angular js $http service

Tags: angularjs

How can get value from the Promise return by $http service

```
>d {$$state: Object}
 $$state: Object
 status: 1
 value: Array[1]
 __proto__: Object
 __proto__: Object
```

How to get the **value** in the **d** object

```
s.states = '';
$http.get('/api/random').then(function(response) {
  s.states = response;
 }, function(error) {

}).finally(function() {

})
console.log(s.states);
```

which shows the above result. $$state so how can get the value from it?

Comment: have you tried d.value ?

Comment: By calling `promise.then(function(value) { acessValueHere(value); })`, as for all promises. Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above:

```
promise.then(function(value) { 
      // Value contains the data received in the response
   }, function(error) {
      // This is called when error occurs.
   }
)
```

The promise itself does not contain a value. It returns the value in the future ("promises" to return a value) when it's available. And when it becomes available (or not), one of two callbacks passed to then() methods gets triggered.
So basically, you should make calls like this:

```
$http.get('/api/random').then(function(response) {
    // Do some stuff with response.
});
```

You can pass a callback to finally() method callback, which will be run regardless of success or error in promise.

```
$http.get('/api/random').then(function(response) {
    // This one is triggered in case of successful response.
}, function(error) {
    // This code runs in case of error
}).finally(function() {
    // And this block will be triggered anyway after the promise returns.
});
```

Comment: You probably need to check the Network tab of your developer tools to see what you request and what you get in response.

Comment: i print the response it shows the above result $$state object

Comment: Based on the code snipped you added: "console.log(s.states);" executes BEFORE  "s.states = response"; So basically it should print empty string assigned above. The output above shows that you are trying to print the promise itself (like console.log($http.get(...)), and $$state.status equal to 1 means that the promise is already resolved. Try console.log(response) in the first callback and inspect what it logs.

Comment: i want the result outside the $http

Comment: That's how promises work. You cannot stop the code execution and wait until promise returns. However, your scope is still available in the callbacks, so you can use anything you need in combination with response.